# Mysql Query to Delete Duplicate Wordpress Comments?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I had an issue with Disqus whereby it created duplicate comments on many posts, sometimes 4 duplicates of the same comment. I've been going through to try and manually remove these but we have more than 10K comments total and unfortunately, this happened haphazardly whereby it only happened to some of the posts. So...

does anyone know of a mysql query whereby I could detect and delete duplicate comments by searching for entries that match in terms of the comment itself or the author? The comment IDs are not duplicate (it created new comment IDs for each) so Im not sure how to do this in mysql (plus Im not very good at it :-)... Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There's a good tutorial here: [How to delete duplicate rows with SQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/10/11/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-with-sql/)

Answer (score 3):

Improving on Blackbarn's suggestion, try this (after backing up the db):

```
global $wpdb;

$comments = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."_comments"
   ." ORDER BY comment_post_ID, comment_content");

$prev = NULL;

foreach($comments as $comment) {

  if ($prev && $prev->comment_content == $comment->comment_content
    && $prev->comment_post_ID == $comment->comment_post_ID ) { // add maybe other rules here

    $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."_comments WHERE comment_ID = ".$comment->comment_ID);

  }
  else
    $prev = $comment;
}
```

Comment: This worked great, but there are problems with the quotations in your query. It works perfectly if you fix the line with the query:

$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."_comments WHERE comment_ID == ".$comment->comment_ID);

Comment: Russell, thanks for proof-reading. :) I edited the code as you suggested

Comment: Although I've found that it only worked for some of the posts. I believe that it may only run the queries on the posts being displayed on the current page. So if you only have 25 posts displayed on your main page, it won't run the queries for older posts. I haven't found a way around it, although I haven't since tried. I suppose you could have all posts display on a page and run the same query if you needed to.

Comment: This line needs to be changed from: $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."_comments WHERE comment_ID == " to $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."_comments WHERE comment_ID = "

I.E. the double "==" should just be a single "="

Comment: @j-man86, you are right. In my defense, I modified the code from another answer that also used '==' in place of '='. The '==' is a habit from all the PHP, JavaScript, etc. Anyway, I've corrected the line.

Answer (score 2):

Write a simple PHP script to clean your comments table (but make a backup before you do it).

Pseudo Code:

// get all the comments

// compare each comment with each comment

// if the content of the comment is the same (or compare all values except of the id, if you want to be sure that nothing gets broken), delete the comment with the higher id

It will be something like this:

```
global $wpdb;

$comments = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."_comments");

foreach($comments as $comment) {

foreach($comments as $compare) {

if(($comment->comment_content == $compare->comment_content) && ($comment->comment_ID != $compare->comment_ID )) { // add maybe other rules here

$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."_comments WHERE comment_ID == $compare->comment_ID");

}

}
```

Not tested, so use and improve with care...

Database with comments table: http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/9e/WP3.0-ERD.png

Comment: Thanks.  I think I found a great answer here - http://www.scriptygoddess.com/archives/2010/05/21/the-blogger-to-wordpress-move-from-hell/

Comment: A good solution too, I think. This is how you do it in SQL/phpmyadmin, which is probably even faster.