# Error in php - Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object

Tags: php

I have wordpress blog and I have massive comments under some post. I found recently that some comments are duplicated two or three times. I want to use php code that removes duplicate elements from table wp_comments from mysql database of Wordpress (by opening php file on server). I used this code:

```
<?php
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php' );
global $wpdb;

$comments = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."_comments"
   ." ORDER BY comment_post_ID, comment_content");

$prev = NULL;

foreach($comments as $comment) {

  if ($prev && $prev->comment_content == $comment->comment_content
    && $prev->comment_post_ID == $comment->comment_post_ID ) {

    $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."_comments WHERE comment_ID == ".$comment->comment_ID);

  }
  else
    $prev = $comment;
}
?>
```

and I got this error:

*> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object in  .../commentsremoving.php on line 5*

**UPDATE:**

**Thanks to Sheikh Heera I have now no error message, but my code doesn't work - no duplicated comments were deleted. Any ideas why?**

Comment: You don't appear to be defining `$wpdb` anywhere... The `global` keyword has no meaning in the code you have given.

Comment: var_dump the $wpdb variable pls

Comment: The global $wpdb variable is correct, so my guess is you're not requiring WordPress' wp-load.php at the top of this file, which is required to access all of the WordPress functions.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you want to use WordPress' functionality outside of `WordPress` you can use

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php' );
```

Then you can use WordPress's functionality. [Check This.](http://www.stormyfrog.com/using-wpdb-outside-wordpress/) If you want to just access the database functions then

```
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php' );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php' );
if (!$wpdb) {
    $wpdb = new wpdb( DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
} else {
    global $wpdb;
}
```

Comment: thanks, it helped!! I have now no error message but my code doesn't work - no duplicated comments were deleted ;-/

Comment: [Check this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802996/mysql-query-to-delete-duplicate-wordpress-comments).

Answer (score 0):

Stick the following in your code after line 5. Does the script show any errors in the page now?

```
$wpdb->print_error();
```

Comment: Now I have no errors (even with $wpdb->print_error(); line ) but my code doesn't work like it should.

Comment: What happens if you put $wpdb->print_error(); at the bottom of your script? Right before the closing ?>

Comment: Nothing, I have blank page after loading this file. Comments still there.

Comment: Are you connected to the database? What do you see with:        echo mysql_error();                                                at the end of the script.

Comment: To debug a bit, put echo 'It works'; in the if statement, just before your Delete query. Then at least when the if statement finds a duplicate, you will at least see 'It works' printed to the screen. It should be printed for every duplicate that is found. This will just show you that the if statement is finding duplicates in the comments, and can let you narrow in on the Delete query as the culprit. If you are still having trouble getting the query to work, you can post another question about the query.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're not requiring the wp-load.php at the top of this file. To load up WordPress so you can use its global variables and functions, this file is required. Try putting this at the top of your file before the global variable:

```
require( '/path/to/wp-load.php' );
```