# Mysql delete duplicate comments?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I want to clean up duplicated content on a comments table (1M rows) where users have posted twice (or more) the same comments. However I want to keep one instance of any repeated comment.

Here is the query that I came up with which finds and groups those comments:

```
SELECT author, body, COUNT(*) as count
FROM  db.comment
GROUP BY body
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

But don't know how to remove the repeated rows while leaving only one untouched. 
I have seen similar questions but none worked for me. So appreciate your hints.

Update:

```
mysql> describe comment;
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| author  | varchar(60) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| body    | longtext    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| post_id | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Does your `comment` table have any sort of unique id?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861799/remove-all-but-one-row-with-duplicate-values

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql Query to Delete Duplicate Wordpress Comments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802996/mysql-query-to-delete-duplicate-wordpress-comments)

Comment: @PeterM No it does not.

Comment: @helpYou That question is php-specific. My site is not in php and the question here  is a pure sql one.

Comment: The `id` and `post_id` sure sounds like a unique id's!

Comment: @PeterM sorry, sql noob here. I just added the table description.

Comment: if there are 2 rows or more duplicate comments on your table, is there an unique column to makes it different? So we have a condition to delete another rows something like `delete from table where comment = 'test' and id > 1` which `id` is an unique field.

Comment: One easy way ALTER IGNORE TABLE comment ADD UNIQUE (body)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike other DBMS, MySQL has a possibility to select all fields from table but do a grouping by only one of them. In this case only the first record of each group will be selected.

Do the job in two steps:

save IDs to remain in a temporary table:

```
INSERT INTO temp_comment(id)
SELECT id
FROM db.comment
GROUP BY author, body
```

delete all rows except the saved ones:

```
DELETE FROM db.comment WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM temp_comment);
```

Of course you need the `temp_comment` table to exist.

Comment: That would be one-off. Would you please elaborate on how to do so?

Comment: the nested query did not work on mysql 5.5 however the temp_comment trick worked like a charm. Please edit your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM  comments
  GROUP BY author,body
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
 )
AND author IN(
  SELECT author
  FROM  comments
  GROUP BY author,body
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  )
AND body IN(
  SELECT body
  FROM  comments
  GROUP BY author,body
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  );
```

To `delete` the duplicate rows, change `SELECT *` to `DELETE`

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/174f8a/1/0)

***Update***

To improve query performance, you can try this :

```
SELECT * FROM comments c
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT id,author,body
  FROM  comments
  GROUP BY author,body
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
 ) AS t
ON c.id NOT IN(t.id) AND c.author IN(t.author) AND c.body IN(t.body)
```

Comment: @supermario I updated the answer. To improvement query performance. Not sure that was what you want. But it faster then prev query (with same result of course)

Comment: I'm afraid the second query was not faster either. both queries took ages and did not return anything.